# How can I give names to Rust slices without taking ownership?

Tags: rust, slice, ownership

In the context of a crypto problem, to decrease verbosity, I'm "naming" a slice of `v` as `block`, doing some stuff to it, but then trying to verify the result of `do_stuff` on the **whole** of `v`:

```
fn x() {
    let mut v = vec![0; 32];
    let block = &mut v[0..16];

    do_stuff(block);
    check_stuff(&v);
    do_stuff(block);
}

fn do_stuff(_: &mut [i32]) {}
fn check_stuff(_: &[i32]) {}
```

The borrow checker complains:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `v` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
 --> src/lib.rs:6:17
  |
3 |     let block = &mut v[0..16];
  |                      - mutable borrow occurs here
...
6 |     check_stuff(&v);
  |                 ^^ immutable borrow occurs here
7 |     do_stuff(block);
  |              ----- mutable borrow later used here
```

I'm aware of the kind of guarantee this is trying to provide. However, assuming I know what I'm doing, is there an idiomatic way to give a name to the slice without having to use `do_stuff(&mut v[0..16])` or having to make copies every time?

Comment: This seems like mostly an aesthetic problem. I would probably define a newtype for the `vec` and provide a method `block()` on it that returns the first block. Whether you consider this worth the trouble depends on how much you care.

Comment: But how could I make this method return something that I can edit, and whose edits have effect on the original vector, without "blocking" the original vector with a mutable borrow?

Comment: You would simply use `v.block()` wherever you have `block` now. This will create a new borrow in each `do_stuff()` call, which will be dropped by the end of the expression.